# Show notifications in app

Tags: android, notifications, window-managers

Well, this is kind of a longshot.
I'm trying to display the user notifications inside my app, like in a listview or something...
I tried to just turn the screen on for lockscreen.
**But**, when using this code:

```
 WindowManager.LayoutParams params = getWindow().getAttributes();
 getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
 params.screenBrightness = 1;
 getWindow().setAttributes(params);
```

It just turn the screen on to the app itself.

Maybe there is a way to get the notifications from the notification center and view them in the app?
Or turn the screen on to the lock screen?
**Thank you.**

**EDIT:**

> I'll explain. My friend can't touch the phone, and he want to see every X minutes if there is new notifications/sms/whatsapp and such. So I started develop runOnUiThread to turn the screen on and off every X minutes. But, the problem is that the screen turn on to the app and not to the lockscreen where there is all the notifications. So, I have 2 options. Or find a way to turn the screen on to the lock screen, or turn the screen on for the app and pull all the notifications as a listview in the app.

Comment: I don´t really understand your question, but I guess....why just don´t make a custom listview item where you pass all information from the notification?

Comment: I'll explain.
My friend can't touch the phone, and he want to see every X minutes if there is new notifications/sms/whatsapp and such.
So I started develop runOnUiThread to turn the screen on and off every X minutes.
But, the problem is that the screen turn on to the app and not to the lockscreen where there is all the notifications.
So, I have 2 options.
Or find a way to turn the screen on to the lock screen, or turn the screen on for the app and pull all the notifications as a listview in the app.

Comment: and what´s the deal behind turning the screen on and off every x minutes?

Comment: Hi, I edited my comment.